# How to draw a text with perspective using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to add a text to a video using ffmpeg and it needs to be with perspective like in the image.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmI7U.png)

i have tried with perspective but i get perspective into the whole video not only the text.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a text overlay, so your best option is to pick a `perspective` font and use that, with the `drawtext` filter.

Here's an example with the font `Therp`. It isn't perfect but might point you in the right direction.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=./.fonts/Therp.ttf:text='Perspective': x=300: y=300:font='Therp Regular':fontsize=40:fontcolor=white:" -c:a copy -f matroska - | ffplay -autoexit -i -
```

Result:

[image]